# Detect upload/download bandwidth of ftp from script

Tags: linux, unix, ftp, bandwidth

My system: `Xubuntu 16.10 x64`.

I have script, where I can upload or download file to/from ftp server (vsftpd).

I want print to console (or get local variable) speed data, like: "time 30 s, average speed 777KB/s.

Is ftp or any other console tool can help me?

I do not saying about way: fix time before upload file, measure time interval on finish upload and calculate: file size / time.

Comment: use [lftp](http://lftp.tech/)

Comment: lftp do not show target speed, only on progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wget` program from [gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) lets you retrieve files from ftp servers given a URL and prints out progress and bandwidth report:

```
[nevin-mac-mini:~] nevin% wget -nv --show-progress ftp://ftp.ccs.somehost./pub/dal/Negoplan.sea.bin
Negoplan.sea.bin    100%[===================>]   2.60M  1.28MB/s    in 2.0s    
2016-12-01 22:21:18 URL: ftp://ftp.ccs.somehost./pub/dal/Negoplan.sea.bin [2728192] -> "Negoplan.sea.bin" [1]
[nevin-mac-mini:~] nevin%
```